# how to give separate height and width constraint for specified screen size for eg giving different constraints for iphone and ipad?

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift4, xcode9

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! viewTableViewCell
let head = titlelist[indexPath.row] as! String
cell.lbl.text = head.uppercased()    
if(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 1366)
{
    cell.img.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 216).isActive = true
    cell.img.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 395).isActive = true
    self.view.updateConstraints()
}
```

I want to change the width and height constraint for my imageview img in cell.but its not updating.any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you design this cell in a separate `Xib` or as prototype cell in `Storyboard`?

Comment: i did it in storboard

Comment: Have you programmatically add imageView in cell? or just add imageView using `Drag & Drop` ?

Comment: image view using drag and drop and gave it a fixed height and width.which is suitable for iphone. and  i am trying to give new height and width constraints for ipad through code

Comment: you can do it using storyboard as well.

Comment: how to do it through storyboard

Comment: I have demonstrate it with screenshots in an answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in below Image. Select your constraint lets say 'Width' and after select look at the left opened panel you'll see a `+` button before `constant` just tap on it a pop up will open with a menu like

- Width:  Compact
- Height: Regular
- Width:  Any

This is for iPhone. To create another constant for iPad just change width form `Compact` to `Regular`

[image][image][image]

Now your constraint has two constant variables. One for iPhones and one for iPads. Assign different constant values as per your requirement.

> PS: You should not change Height and Width from `+` is different
>   thing. `Compact Width and Regular Height` means an `iPhone` and
>   `Regular Width and Regular Height` means an `iPad`

Comment: do you have soucre file where i can go deeper abouth the subject

Comment: Sure. Download it from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VQkvG_hWNfvKaCriYn0qGToGWks3-nSg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Open the storyboard. I have a cell with height 300 and imageView with height & width = 100 for iPhones and 250 for iPads. You can check it using preview feature of storyboard instead of directly running the app.

Comment: i was referring to documentation regarding this topic.i have sucessfully changed my width and height constants

Comment: `Adaptive UI` => https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/
`UITraitCollection` => Doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
cell.img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    //iPad
    cell.img.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
    cell.img.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
} 
else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
    //iPhone
    cell.img.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 216).isActive = true
    cell.img.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 395).isActive = true
} 

cell.img.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
cell.img.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
cell.img.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.centerXAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
```

this requires dynamic table height

Comment: what should be the offset value . compiler is yelling at me  "unresolved identifier offset"

Comment: it's padding replace it will any number , no offset in edit

Comment: how to give dynamic table height